# wordpress to use <!-break--> in addition to <!--more-->

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm importing posts from a Drupal feed that uses `<!--break-->` instead of `<!--more-->`.  I'm thinking that I could scan the content and replace all instances of `<!--break-->`  with `<!--more->` from my functions php, but it seems like there would be an easier way to make the function that is already looking for `<!--more-->` validate and trigger off of `<!--break-->` as well.  Any ideas or other innovative ways that I can trigger the page break from `<!--break-->` in Wordpress?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to escape  <!--break--> and <!--more-->

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel here...  str_replace("<!--break-->","<!--more-->",$string); is a one liner.

Comment: fair enough @quasivivo, altho I'm specifically asking for any other ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just modify the existing function. open up the `wp-includes/post.php` file. Find the `get_extended` function and replace

```
if ( preg_match('/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $post, $matches) ) {
```

with

```
if ( preg_match('/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $post, $matches) || preg_match('/<!--break(.*?)?-->/', $post, $matches) ) {
```

Comment: Any chance of of making this pluggable or outside hacking the core?

Comment: Yeah ofcourse it is. Read up on how to make a plugin: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: I think it would be better if it was added to the core.  Surely there's no good reason to make support for `<!--break-->` optional.